# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') at MapComponent.ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angularjs, web, bing-maps

I am using bing map ( npm angular-maps package) to show the map once the user has entered the location I am getting the latitude and longitude from MapQuest and getting this response correctly but whenever I am trying to show the map it's showing me the error
I am the below link as a reference
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bing-basic-map-with-single-marker-hprtgv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
  <x-map #xmap [Options]="_options" [Box]="_box" *ngIf="lng != 0 && lat != 0">
    <x-map-marker
      [Latitude]="lat"
      [Longitude]="lng"
      [Title]="'My Marker'"
      [IconInfo]="_iconInfo"
    >
    </x-map-marker>
  </x-map>
```

this is defined in the .ts file

```
 _markerTypeId = MarkerTypeId;
  _options: IMapOptions = {
    disableBirdseye: false,
    disableStreetside: false,
    navigationBarMode: 1,
    zoom: 6,
  };

  _box: IBox = {
    maxLatitude: this.lat + 47,
    maxLongitude: this.lng + 47,
    minLatitude: this.lat - 38,
    minLongitude: this.lng - 38,
  };

  _iconInfo: IMarkerIconInfo = {
    markerType: MarkerTypeId.FontMarker,
    fontName: 'FontAwesome',
    fontSize: 48,
    color: 'red',
    markerOffsetRatio: { x: 0.5, y: 1 },
    text: '\uF276',
  };
```

this is my App.ts file

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnChanges,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { IBox, IMapOptions, IMarkerIconInfo, MarkerTypeId } from 'angular-maps';
import { MapService } from '../Service/map.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('xmap') xmap: any;

  location: string = '';
  response!: any;
  lat: number = 0;
  lng: number = 0;

  _markerTypeId = MarkerTypeId;
  options: IMapOptions = {
    disableBirdseye: false,
    disableStreetside: false,
    navigationBarMode: 1,
    zoom: 6,
  };

  _iconInfo: IMarkerIconInfo = {
    markerType: MarkerTypeId.FontMarker,
    fontName: 'FontAwesome',
    fontSize: 48,
    color: 'red',
    markerOffsetRatio: { x: 0.5, y: 1 },
    text: '\uF276',
  };

  box: IBox = {
    maxLatitude: 32,
    maxLongitude: -92,
    minLatitude: 29,
    minLongitude: -98,
  };
  constructor(private MapService: MapService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.lat != 0 && this.lng != 0) {
      this.box = {
        maxLatitude: this.lat + 47,
        maxLongitude: this.lng + 47,
        minLatitude: this.lat - 38,
        minLongitude: this.lng - 38,
      };
    }
  }

  Value() {
    this.response = this.MapService.GetCoordinate(this.location).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.response = data.results[0].locations[0].latLng;
        this.lat = this.response['lat'];
        this.lng = this.response['lng'];
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

the Lng and lat are the variables in which I am storing the longitude and latitude.

I tried removing the ngIf as the chatgpt was suggesting but it didn't work.
the x-map tag is not getting initialized as I tried to show some data which didn't get rendered

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the lat and lon values? I cant find it either in your question nor in the stackblitz. My guess wouldbe that its asynchronous and angular doesnt know it should update.

Comment: I have added the app.ts file in Question

Comment: The data you receive is updated outside of the angular lifecycle. Try to inject the changeDetectorRef in the constructor and call changeDetectorRef.detectChanges inside the subscribe Block after setting all values and see if it helps

Comment: The problem is my x-map tag is not getting initialized.